# FlexMobileProject, setStyle("textFormat",number) in textArea doesn't work

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flex-mobile

I create dynamic `TextArea` in Flex, I want to change its `fontSize` dynmically, but `setStyle` doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();  
textArea.id = "txtCreaTaskAnalysis" +contatoreNumeroTextAreaCreaTaskAnalysis;  
textArea.left = 140;  
textArea.right = 45;  
textArea.horizontalCenter = 47;  
textArea.height = 110;  
textArea.y = posizioneYTextArea;  
var tfor:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
tfor.size= 25 ;  
textArea.setStyle("textFormat",tfor);  
textArea.text = tfor.size.toString();  
addElement(textArea);
```

I have this code in a `buttonClickHandler`, but the `fontSize` doesn't change.

Help, please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
textArea.setStyle("fontSize",25);
```

I don't think TextArea has a style called "textFormat".